# Independence of two events in a Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, independence

Let $\{X_k:k\geq0\}$ a Standard Brownian motion. Compute the following propability

$$P(X_2>0|X_1>0).$$

The question is: Are $\{X_2\}$ and $\{X_1\}$ independent?

I know:

$$P(X_2>0|X_1>0)=\frac{P(X_2>0\ \cap X_1>0)}{P(X_1>0)}$$
and if I assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then I have to show that
$$P(X_2>0|X_1>0)=P(X_2>0).$$

How can I calculate it?

Comment: they are clearly not independent. If you already know that you are in the upper half-plane, then it is more likely that you will be in the upper half-plane at a subsequent point than it is without having this knowledge.

Comment: By symmetry, $P(X_2>0|X_1>0)=\frac 1 2+\frac 1 2\cdot\frac 1 2=\frac 3 4$.

Comment: @A.S. Could you explain me how you calculate it? I dont' get it. It would be grateful ^^

Comment: Consider two equally likely cases  $X_2-X_1>0$ and $X_2-X_1<0$ and in the latter find $P(X_1>X_2-X_1)$. Use independent increment property of the BM.

Comment: @A.S., thank you, but I have a question: Why can we assume that $X_2-X_1\leq 0$ or $\geq 0$?

Comment: You don't assume. You partition you space into two equal subparts, work with each separately and combine them together.

Comment: I have a last question: Don't we add the probabilities $X_2-X_1>0$ and $X_2-X_1<0$ instead of multiplying? Does it exist a special formula? I want to understand the solution, but I don't really get it ^^